# Addition assignment null issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Hi I'm getting an issue where the Addition assignment `+=` is returning a null value and I'm not sure why this is. Here is an example of this circled in green:

[image]

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
    for (let i = 0; i < res.rowCount; i++) {
        let username = res.rows[i].user_id
        let level = res.rows[i].lvl
        let xp = res.rows[i].xp
        embed.description += `# ${i+1}. **${username}** **Level: ${level}** | **XP: ${xp}**\n`;}
        message.reply({ embeds: [embed]});
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like `embed.description` has a `null` initial value, and concatenating to that will first "stringify" that value.  Observe:

```js
var foo = null;
foo += "test";
console.log(foo);
```

You can conditionally set `embed.description` before updating it, so if it's `null` make it an empty string:

```
embed.description = embed.description ?? '';
```

For example:

```js
var foo = null;
foo = foo ?? '';
foo += "test";
console.log(foo);
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks at the first loop iteration, `embed.description` is `null`, you concatenated null with a string which gives "`null<string>`".

```js
var a = null;
a += "string";
console.log(a);
```

try setting blank/empty string to `embed.description` before for loop, like

```
embed.description = "";
```